# node-webkit with Express on Windows 8 "Error: listen EACCES"

Tags: windows, node.js, angularjs, http, express

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

Error: listen EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:677:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1060:19)
    at listen (net.js:1113:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1188:5)
    at Function.app.listen (C:\workspace\ticketpicker\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:534:24)
    at eval (file:///C:/workspace/ticketpicker/scripts/server/server.js:122:5)
```

This is the error I am getting. I have a node app that is running on node-webkit (the desktop lib) and I have an angularjs front end for it. I am running my server with Express on port 8080 on a Windows 8 machine with the firewall turned off.

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                 // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');           // mongoose for mongodb
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');

var port = 8080; //process.env.PORT || 8080;

 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./templates/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
  });
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(app).listen(port);
app.listen(port);
```

This is my server's code. I want my server to listen on some port so I can make http requests from my angular frontend so I can grab data from the node server.

Can someone help me out with figuring out how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're listening on the same port twice. Get rid of the `app.listen(port);`.

Comment: Rookie move on my part...trying a fix without taking out some of the old code...I'll let you know if this fixes it. Thanks!!